# Error: Could not find or load main class Sample.Main in JavaFx project

Tags: java, javafx, noclassdeffounderror

I am developing a JavaFx project in Eclipse IDE with one of my friend. The Java versions are same in both of our computers. but when I try to run the project in my own computer it gives the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

Although it gives above error, `Main.java` class is in the package called 'Sample'.

I have already went through some answers related to my problem but could not find a solution. I configured the build paths as follows too. but it doesn't run as expected.

**Configure build path:** [Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRtl9.png)

Following is the **Main.class**

```
package Sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("top.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1100, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I am much obliged if somebody can please help me to find the cause for this problem and how to rectify it.

Comment: I did not type any command. Just select the main class and click run button in the Eclipse IDE. Other sample projects are working fine when I did so. I cannot understand the reason why I am getting this error.

Comment: Not sure ... but you really should use lowercase names for packages,

Comment: This is probably related to the run configuration of the project.
Mark the project in your Project's view, Menu Run > Run configuration... and above Java Application have look how Eclipse will run the project.

Comment: In Eclipse right-click Main.java select Run as > java application. If this does not work you'll have to inspect the run configuration by   Run as > Run Configurations.